# Open entire module file tree in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, directory-structure, file-structure

Not sure if this is possible, but I have many multi module projects. Each module essentially follows `module/src/main/java/packages..`. This is shown in photo below

[image: file structure]

Currently I have to click src -> main -> java -> etc....

Ideally I would like to just click `src` and have the whole directory open up. This would save me a good amount of time in the long run. I have searched for an Android Studio setting that does this but no luck. Would I have to write some kind of script for this? I'm lost on how to achieve this

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to navigate to a specific file in the tree or you want to see the whole tree?

Comment: whole tree..I want to avoid the click chain of 
`src` -> `main` -> `java` -> `pkg1` -> `pkg2` -> `pkg3..` -> `etc`

I've looked at the project structure settings and `flatten packages` helps but doesn't provide the behavior i'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the key `*` on the numeric keypad, it will automatically expand the tree. This setting can be configured with a different key by searching:

> Fully Expand Tree Node

Comment: This is as close as I could get, I'll need to play around and see if I can prevent it from opening up `test`, etc.. but this does open up the entire tree which I what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think *exactly* what you're looking for exists (to my knowledge, and I've been using Android Studio since its beta).

I think the closest thing you're looking for are these two things: 'Compact Middle Packages' and/or setting your project view to 'Android' (see screenshots below).

I hope this helps, if not, you could [create a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533) to the Android Studio team.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Set your project view to 'Android' and select 'Flatten Packages' as shown in image.

[image]

When you expand java it will show list of all packages (check below image).
[image]